# Why values are not the same?

Tags: java, arrays

I have the following piece of code:

```
public int[][][] arrMethod1(){
    for (int idx=0;idx< x;idx++ ){
        arr[idx]=arrMethod2();
        System.out.println("arr "+idx+" is "+Arrays.toString(arr[idx][0]));
        }
    System.out.println("arr0 are "+Arrays.toString(arr[0][0]));
    System.out.println("arr1 are "+Arrays.toString(arr[1][0]));
    return arr;
}
```

When this piece of code is executed, different result is produced within the for loop and different outside. It seems that the `arr[0][0]` is the same as `arr[1][0]`, which is not true within the for loop. myMethod() is a method that initializes `arr[idx]` with a 2D array. For my testing I used a 1D array and `x=2` for simplicity. The purpose is to have `x` different `arr` which are 3D arrays. The rest of the code:

```
private final int[][] arrMethod2(){ 
    final int[] otherArr=arrMethod3();
        for (int idz=0;idz< z;idz++ ){
            int[] toBe=new int[otherArr.length];
            System.arraycopy( otherArr, 0, toBe, 0, otherArr.length );
            newArr2[idz]=change(toBe);
    }
    return newArr2;
}

public int[] arrMethod3(){
    for (int idy = 0; idy < y; idy++){
          double randomInt = randomGenerator.nextDouble();
          newArr3[idy]=(int) Math.round(randomInt);
    }
    return newArr3;

public MyClass(int x,int y, int z){
    this.x=x;
    this.y=y;
    this.z=z;
    this.newArr3 = new int[y];
    this.newArr2 = new int[z][y];
    this.arr = new int[x][z][y];
}
```

Comment: We don't know what `myMethod()` does, which makes it very hard to help you. Please provide a short but *complete* program which demonstrates the problem.

Comment: your program is very vague. what is X ? your arr is a 2-D array it seems, so do you realize that arr[0] is a 1-D array itself?

Comment: Also `arr` appears to be a class instance variable, who knows whats happening to it, do you touch it in myMethod or some other place?

Comment: why is this relevant? myMethod() is just a piece of code that initializes the arr[idx]. It calls for other methods as well. Assume that it assigns each arr[idx] a 10 elements array which is what is printed inside the for loop. e.g `arr 0 is [1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0]` and `arr 1 is [0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1]` but outside we have `arr0 are [0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1]
arr1 are [0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1]`

Comment: @JustCurious `Just a piece of code` === Another point of failure

Comment: I just want to initialize a 3D array during each iteration. Each iteration myMethod() initializes a 2D array by calling another method to initialize a 1D array. Why does this affect the end result?

Comment: Should you have not understood this yet, it is precisely the code you do not show that is the problem

Comment: @JustCurious If you want us to help you, please consider asking questions in a form that we can. A simple, complete, compilable piece of code would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code creates the innermost array (newArr3) exactly once and then only changes the values within that array. You need to create a new one on every call.

Change your Method arrMethod3 like this:

```
public int[] arrMethod3(){
   int[] retVal = new int[y]; // THIS IS THE IMPORANT LINE
   for (int idy = 0; idy < y; idy++){
      double randomInt = randomGenerator.nextDouble();
      retVal[idy]=(int) Math.round(randomInt);
   }
   return retVal;
}
```

You will need to do the same for `newArr2` (in `arrMethod2`) as well.

The reason is that you overwrite the values that you have already passed. Like this:

- init class, define arrays
- first run through loop, assign a value to each element in all arrays
- second run, assign a value to each element in all arrays, thous overwriting the old ones.

But what you need to do is:

- init class, define outer array (only the most outer one!)
- outer loop addresses outer array and calls inner method

  - inner method creates new array and fills it with new data

That way you will have new arrays each time you call an inner method.

Think of it like a house with rooms, each room can hold exactly one thing, if you go through a house and place a desk in each room and then go through the SAME house again and replace the desk with a stool; then in the end you will have a house full of stools.

If you instead fill the house with desks and then go to the next house and fill it with stools, you get two houses with different contents.

(In that example room is your arrMethod3, house is arrMethod2 and the outer array is the street)

Comment: @JustCurious okay, so is is as expected. You need to put the line `int[] newArr3 = new int[y];` into the `arrMethod3()` I'll update my answer.

Comment: @JustCurious please see my edit, I will explain a bit deeper in a moment.

Answer (score 1):

If `myMethod` does not create a new array (`new int[][]` and `new int[]`) but reuses the same memory object, then the same object is put in `arr[0]` and `arr[1]`. Always filled by the new values; the last ones overwrite the earlier ones.

Comment: i initialize `arr` in the class constructor like this this.arr = new int[x][z][y];

Comment: Then the one-dimensional array `arr[idx][0]` maybe should not be substituted by `myMethod`. Change it to `void myMethod(int[] a)`.

Comment: `arr[idx][0]` contains an address of one dimensional array. This address was the result of the initial new. `arr[idx][0] = ...` overwrites this address. Probably `myMethod` (re-)uses one single global `int[]` and returns its address. Causing `arr[idx][0]` and `arr[idx][1]` to point to the same address.

Answer (score 0):

Just to clarify, if I understand correctly from your description, outside of the loop `arr[0][0] & arr[1][0]` are equal. This implies that they are equal even inside of the loop. But what you are saying is incorrect i.e. `arr[0][0] == arr[1][0]` doesn't mean that `arr[0] = arr[1]`, this just means that 0th elements of these 2 arrays are equal. Does that answer your question? or atleast clarify it?

Comment: `arr[0][0]` shouldn't be equal to `arr[1][0]. This is the case inside the loop, which is correct. Outside the loop, arr[0][0] is the same as arr[1][0] which is wrong and which is something i don't understand why us happening.